# Processing payments and piggyback ssl

Tags: ssl, heroku, stripe-payments

I have a website that plans on accepting payment orders. My host (heroku) offers piggyback ssl (free). My payment gateway (stripe) needs ssl in order to process payments. Is heroku piggyback ssl enough to process stripe payments?

**From stripe's site:**

> *If you want to go into production before setting up SSL, you could consider hosting your site with a provider that gives you a secure
>   subdomain. For example, Heroku allows you to host at
>   https://yourapp.heroku.com.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it will work fine.

You could even use a custom domain for your http traffic and then the https://yourapp.herokuapp.com for your SSL if you want to keep the cost down rather than having to buy an SSL and pay for the addon.

Comment: Is there anyway that I could use a custom domain and piggyback ssl without buying the add-on? Example: https ://customdomain.com, and all requests to http ://app.herokuapp.com, https ://app.herokuapp.com and http ://customdomain.com would get transferred to https ://customdomain.com ?

Comment: if you want to use https on your domain you need the addon but I'm not entirely sure naked domain (ie with a host eg www. ) are supported with the Heroku SSL addon due to issues around scaling naked domains.

Comment: My only concern with this setup is that Heroku probably logs all incoming requests somewhere that would have url's + parameters attached. Wouldn't this be an issue?